# Alternative for Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

We are currently using Azure Blob Storage for storing documents like .json, .html and .pdf. Is there any replacement that we can use to move the documents from storage to on-premises ?
Is MongoDB valid alternative?

Comment: This question is off-topic, as it's broad and opinion-soliciting, as well as a tool-recommendation question. There's no right answer to this. And you're comparing apples to oranges, when comparing a document database to an object store such as blob storage.

Answer (score -1):

Based on my understanding, it seems that you want to migrate document assets from Azure Blob Storage to on-premises.

Per my experience, normally consideration for three attributes of IT on-premises infrastructure which include Reliability, Availability, and Maintainability, you need to use some enterprise hardwares & softwares to support the needs, such as Disk Array, SAN switch, HA software and enterprise FileSystem like JFS with NFS.

However, if only consideration for storage hosted on X86 cluster in software, you can choose some distributed FileSystem as the on-premises storage, such as Ceph  or HDFS.

Meanwhile, according to the MongoDB offical [article](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/183689081/storing-large-objects-and-files-in-mongodb), you can directly store these large Objects & files in MongoDB, but there are some limits of Data Size for MongoDB, please care these https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#data.

To use what as on-premises storage only depend on your scenario.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no right answer to give, and there's no possible way for anyone to give an objective answer on whether to use MongoDB (there are so many factors involved, and object size is only one of them).